# Python - Can a variables column be looked up in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'd like to know if it's possible to look up columns from a passed in variable using Python and Sqlite3. Here is the code below:

```
wrenches = db.execute('''
           select w.id, w.desc from wrenches as w
           join users as u on w.dept = u.dept and w.user = u.id
           where u.id = :user
           order by w.id asc''',
           {'user': session['user_id']}).fetchall()
```

The above work fine, but the additional condition I want to check for is if a wrench is shared and is in the same department as the user passed in

```
wrenches = db.execute('''
           select w.id, w.desc from wrenches as w
           join users as u on w.dept = u.dept and w.user = u.id
           where u.id = :user
       >>> or w.shared = 1 and w.dept = :user.dept <<<
           order by w.id asc''',
           {'user': session['user_id']}).fetchall()
```

I can't figure it out so any help appreciated.

Comment: No. You will need to either create 2 different queries or concat the `or` condition. Either way, make sure your code is not exposed to SQL injection

Comment: Another option is to use CASE and pass a parameter to branch on.